# Trying to compile git but libcurl not found in linux

Tags: linux, git, curl, libcurl

I wanna compile git with http/https supported. And I have

```
$ ls /usr/include/curl/
curlbuild.h  curl.h  curlrules.h  curlver.h  easy.h  mprintf.h  multi.h  stdcheaders.h  typecheck-gcc.h
$ ls /usr/lib/libcurl.*
/usr/lib/libcurl.a  /usr/lib/libcurl.la  /usr/lib/libcurl.so.3  /usr/lib/libcurl.so.3.0.0
```

But when I run with `./configure --with-curl`, it still notice

```
checking for curl_global_init in -lcurl... no
```

How to fix that?

ps: My environment could not use `yum install curl-devel`, and I guess 'curl-devel' just offer the c header file and static lib?

Comment: `libcurl-devel` should include the development library `libcurl.so` - on Centos the package description is "Files needed for building applications with libcurl". What distribution are you on and why can't you install the package?

Comment: What's your OS? RedHat?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to install `curl-devel`, provided:

- you are [using the same version of curl than curl-devel](https://serverfault.com/a/386745/783)
- you are [using the right name](https://serverfault.com/a/701452/783) `curl-devel` (which you are apparently)

It will include `/usr/lib64/libcurl.so`