# How to compile Git from source with libcurl.so which is NOT under the system folder

Tags: git, curl, compilation

I am trying to compile Git from the source. My commands are as below.

```
make configure
./configure --prefix=/home/xxx/ins/git-2.34 --with-curl=/home/xxx/ins/curl-7.80.0
make
```

Under /home/xxx/ins/curl-7.80.0, I have installed the curl lib.
But there are still the errors about the symbols in the curl lib are undefined reference while building the git.

```
http.o: In function `process_curl_messages':
/home/xxx/sw2/git-2.34.1/http.c:228: undefined reference to `curl_multi_info_read'
http.o: In function `xmulti_remove_handle':
/home/xxx/sw2/git-2.34.1/http.c:221: undefined reference to `curl_multi_remove_handle'
http.o: In function `finish_active_slot':
/home/xxx/sw2/git-2.34.1/http.c:198: undefined reference to `curl_easy_getinfo'
/home/xxx/sw2/git-2.34.1/http.c:207: undefined reference to `curl_easy_getinfo'
/home/xxx/sw2/git-2.34.1/http.c:210: undefined reference to `curl_easy_getinfo'
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to compile git but libcurl not found in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45808030/trying-to-compile-git-but-libcurl-not-found-in-linux)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest building curl-config (as part of curl build) and exporting `CURL_CONFIG` environment variable pointing to the curl-config binary.

Now when you run `./configure` script in the folder with git source code it will locate the curl library corresponding to the curl-config binary.

Another option may be to export `CURL_LDFLAGS="-L/home/xxx/ins/curl-7.80.0 -lcurl"` before running `./configure` script in the folder with git source code.